# Using SQL to categorize a multiple rows of a column using Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition

A tricky conundrum I'm trying to figure out in Snowflake.

Let's say I have data like this

```
ID    tag
001     A
001     A
002     B
003     A
004     1
003     1
005     B
005     2
004     B
002     C
006     A
006     2
006     A
```

And basically, my goal is I would like to categorize each ID into a unique table on the following criteria. So across ALL of a given ID...

- If at any given point the ID is equal to 1 AND/OR A, then "GROUPA"
- If at any given point the ID is equal to 2 AND/OR B, then "GROUPB"
- If 1 AND B appear to the same ID OR if 2 AND A appear to the same ID, then NULL

And if any other values appear, no issue, I only care about `1,2,A,B` ; each ID will have a row with atleast one of these.

So the resulting DF will be...

```
ID      GROUP
001     GROUPA
002     GROUPB
003     GROUPA
004     NULL
005     GROUPB
006     NULL
```

Notice, `004` and `006` were nulled out because in `004` both `1` and `B` appeared. Similarly, even though `A` appeared twice in `006`, the `2` does not match and thus is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation, here: [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    CASE WHEN COUNT_IF(tag IN ('1','A')) > 0 AND COUNT_IF(tag IN ('2','B')) > 0 THEN NULL
         WHEN COUNT_IF(tag IN ('1','A')) > 0 THEN 'GROUPA'
         WHEN COUNT_IF(tag IN ('2','B')) > 0 THEN 'GROUPB'
    END AS grp
FROM tab
WHERE tag IN ('1', '2', 'A', 'B')
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: I think the first condition should be `or`, not `and`.